# Convert a string formatted as an array TO a real array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a POST Rest API that has a parameter that is called $arrProducts.
The parameter should be an array.
But the value that is sent to the API is not an array, but a string, with the form of an array.

Let me give an example of the string parameter that is passed:

```
"$arrProducts = array(array("product_id"=>'79',"qty"=>2,"options" =>array("525"=>'')),array("product_id"=>'41',"qty"=>3),"options"=>array("195"=>'')));"
```

This parameter even though it looks like an array is not. It is a string. So I tried to make it more like an array.

```
$stringVar = $_POST['arrProducts'];
$str = rtrim($stringVar, ";"); //To lose the semicolon at the end of the string
$arrProducts = substr($str, 15); // To lose the first part of the string "$arrProducts = " to make it formatted exactly like an array.
```

So after this I ended up with the pure array form `"array(array("product_id"=>'79',"qty"=>2,"options" =>array("525"=>'')),array("product_id"=>'41',"qty"=>3),"options"=>array("195"=>'')))"`

And now my question is how can I convert this string to an array?

OK listen what I did was to first change the way the data was trasmitted to the Rest API.
I used json_encode.
Then In my Rest API i grabbed the Data using json_decode.

Now here is the new issue I have.
The format of the arrProducts is as follows. I have a problem parsing the json_decode thought.

```
$product_id = "45";
        $qty = 20;
        $option_type_id_for_option_id_151 = '826';
        $option_type_id_for_option_id_124 = '657,658,';
        $option_type_id_for_option_id_126 = 'Test for field option';

    $arrProducts = array(
        array(
            "product_id" => $product_id,
            "qty" => $qty,
            "options" => array(         
                "151" => $option_type_id_for_option_id_151,
                "124" => $option_type_id_for_option_id_124,
                '126' => $option_type_id_for_option_id_126
            )
        ),
        array(
            "product_id" => '60',
            "qty" => '1',
            "options" => array(         
                "156" => '862',
                "167" => '899',
                "168" => '902',
                "159" => '877',
                "160" => '889,890,891,'
            )
        ),
        array(
            "product_id" => '58',
            "qty" => '1',
            "options" => array(         
                "174" => '938',
                "176" => '943',
                "178" => ''
            )
        )

    );
```

The problem is with the way I will parse the data using json_decode:
Here is what I wrote but for some reason there is a problem in the options array.

```
$stringVar = $_POST['arrProducts'];
$arrProductsVar = json_decode($stringVar, TRUE);
$i = 0;
        $arrProducts = array();
        if ($arrProductsVar !== NULL)
        { 

            foreach ($arrProductsVar['arrProducts'] as $arrProduct){
                $options = array();
                foreach($arrProduct['options'] as $key => $val){
                     $options[$key] = $val;
                }

                $arrProducts[$i] = array('product_id' => $arrProduct['product_id'],'qty' => $arrProduct['qty'], 'options' => $options);
                $i++;
            }

        }
```

Can anyone see any classic error in this code? Cause it is not working for some reason. Probably due to the $options array. I think it is not formatted well.

Comment: Well, don't know how trusted the source is..but if it's a valid PHP declaration of an array `eval` would work - but should be a last resort with unknown code.

Comment: eval() won't work as it currently stands. You mix the quotes up too much so can't pass it as a string to eval anyway.  You would need to clean it up first. Plus eval should be avoided... its not a good idea especially on API inputs

Comment: By the way, your array is malformed anyway, so if the intention is to have valid PHP in the string, its not working.  You have too many brackets.

Comment: I have wrote the array by hand so I might have some mistakes, but the string that is passed as a parameter which is formatted as an array is valid.

Comment: This is nonsense, use a format that is easy to decode/encode for example JSON. If you insist on using this format, you'll have to code your own parser which will make the process complexer while it wasn't even a problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. That is why I changed the logic of the whole thing. But I have a new issue now. I describe it in the details of the question. Let me know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

If you have to pass the array as a string, I would suggest you use php's `json_encode` and `json_decode` methods to pass a JSON string on the REST route, but have an array where you need it.

*Updated based on changes to question:*

You have this line in your code

```
foreach ($arrProductsVar['arrProducts'] as $arrProduct){
```

However the code that you use to describe the array format will not create an `arrProducts` key in the `$arrProductsVar`

Try

```
foreach ($arrProductsVar as $arrProduct){
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have to pass it as a string, as this string is gradually created using javascript, to construct this array format. So what you suggest is to take this constructed string which is formated as an array and json_encode it? Will this work? Isn't is at the same scope? I will be trying to json_encode a string, not an array.

Comment: It just seems strange to build a PHP array as a string in this format, especially in JS.  JSON is the Javascript Object Notation, so it would be far easier to construct a JSON string in JS and pass it to the PHP URL than to build this particular string.  But obviously you need to have control over the JS to do this

Comment: Yes I had told the developer that created the javascript that is sending the parameter to the API, to send to the parameter $arrProducts, an array that will have the above format that I mentioned. And what he did was send a string that is formatted as an array. So now I have to figure out how I can convert this string to a real array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
$arrProducts = array("arrProducts"=>array(whatever));
$dataToPost = json_encode($arrProducts);
```

Now in your REST code,

```
$stringVar = $_POST['arrProducts'];
$arrProducts = json_decode($stringVar);
```

so $arrProducts contains your data in array format

Comment: Could you please also write the first part in javascript, as the data is sent from a javascript code.

Comment: If you have a javascript array use JSON.stringify(yourArray), then send it via ajax post or get.

Comment: Ok I will try this and i will let you know! I am open to other ideas too.

Comment: if you are using jquery, then you can try .serialize() also.

Comment: did stringify work ? make sure you declare var yourArray = {} if you have associative array;

Comment: I did not tested it yet. I have to contact the javascript developer, and then I will edit the REST code. I will let you know.

Comment: I tested it. I have edited the details of the thread. Let me know if you can help with my new question.

Comment: try doing this 
$arrProductsVar['arrProducts'] = json_decode($stringVar, TRUE);
in line no 2.

OR .. remove index 'arrProducts' from forearch.. ie. foreach($arrProductsVar as arrProduct)